# What is the use of "Namespace" in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

The only information I can find regarding namespaces in MongoDB is that namespace is a combination of collections and database name.
But what is the use of a namespace in a project?

Answer (score 4):

The official definition of "namespace" is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/):

> The canonical name for a collection or index in MongoDB. The namespace is a combination of the database name and the name of the collection or index, like so: [database-name].[collection-or-index-name]. All documents belong to a namespace. See Namespaces.

One way of defining "namespace" in MongoDB is it is "a fully qualified collection or view name".

An argument can be made that the MongoDB's definition of "namespace" does not match the generally accepted [computer science one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).

Note that collections and views share *namespace* (to use the CS term). Meaning it's not possible to have a collection `foo` and a view `foo` in the same database, as well as `db.foo` could refer to a collection or a view.

Answer (score 2):

Each database is organized into namespaces, which are mapped to WiredTiger files. This abstraction separates the storage engine’s internal details from the MongoDB query layer.